# Anaconda Python 3.5 Install PyODBC

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pyodbc

I meed to install PyODBC to connect Anaconda with Python 3.5 to database. Support for PyODBC only goes up to Python 3.3. I tried download the PyODBC adapter for Python 3.5 from here http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyodbc ,but I cant seem to get it installed. Thanks!

Comment: I get error SyntaxError: invalid syntax  when I run                                           pip install pyodbc35.whl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have pyodbc running with Python 3.5. Have you tried:

```
pip install pyodbc==3.0.10
```

Here's the latest / greatest version, it is no longer on Google Code: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc

Comment: I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Where are you getting invalid syntax, from the pip command? Where are you running it from? What's the output of 'pip --version'?

Comment: this way through cmd said I need Visual C++ 14.0. The one using conda promt below worked

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyodbc=3.0.10
```

Also, check here to make sure you'll install the latest version

https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pyodbc